# Saving a Matrix in MatLab

Tags: matlab, matrix, save

I have a MatLab program that generates a large 1000x1000 matrix. How can I save this matrix for use in future programs. Ideally, I want to save it as a particular variable. Here is the code that I am using.

function A = generateSPDmatrix(n)

A = rand(n,n); % generate a random n x n matrix

A = A+A'; 
A = A*A';

A = A + n*eye(n);

end

Comment: You could have answered this question yourself by opening the built-in documentation (`doc` or F1) and search for "save". I'm all for helping beginners, but seriously, not even the tiniest bit of research?!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use it in future Matlab programs, you could do it like this:

```
save('A.mat', 'A');
```

To load, just do it like this:

```
load('A.mat');
```

Comment: Just to add to this that saving mat files preserves variable names (as the OP requested). So if you did `save('vars.mat','A','B','C');` And then `load('vars.mat');` You would then have the variables named `A`,`B` and `C` in your workspace. So give them the names you want BEFORE saving them.

Answer (score 0):

```
% the file path is current path.
save('A.txt', 'A','-ascii');
% save to your file path
save('D:\test.txt','m','-ascii')
```

'D:\test.txt': file name and path

'm': your matrix

'-ascii': 8-digit ASCII format

See the matlab Help. Search the save(Save workspace variables to file) function

save(filename, variables, format) saves in the specified format: '-mat' or '-ascii'. You can specify the format option with additional inputs such as variables, '-struct' , '-append', or version.

Comment: Please add some explanation as well. This answer has been flagged as low quality.